# Let $G$ be a finite abelian group with $(|H|, n) = 1$. Prove that every element $g \in G$ can be written as $h^n$ for some $h \in G$.

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, solution-verification

I am trying to prove the below result.

> Let $G$ be a finite abelian group, and $n$ any integer relatively prime to the order $|G|$ of $G$. Prove that every element $g \in G$ can be written as $h^n$ for some $h \in G$.

This is my attempt.

> Fix $g \in G$ with $|g| = \left \lvert \langle g \rangle \right \rvert := m$. By Lagrange's theorem, $m$ divides $|G|$. Since $|G|$ is relatively prime to $n$, $m$ is relatively prime to $n$, i.e., $(m,n) = 1$. By Bezout's lemma, there exist $r,s \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $mr + ns = 1$. So
> \begin{align*}
> g = g^1 = g^{mr + ns} = (g^m)^r (g^s)^n = e^r (g^s)^n = (g^s)^n,
> \end{align*}
> so taking $h = g^s$ proves the result.

The only step I am not completely sure about (I'm confident that it's true, but I can't prove it) is that $m$ is relatively prime to $n$. If $m = 1$, the result is obvious: For any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $(a,n) = 1$. If $m > 1$, if $(m,n) > 1$, there is some common divisor $k >1$ of $m,n$. So $m = kj$ for some $j \in \mathbb{N}$. But $m \mid |H|$, so $kj \mid |H|$, so $k \mid 
|G|$, so $(|H|,n) \geq k > 1$, a contradiction.

What I want to say is that if $m,n$ are not relayively prime, then neither are $|G|$, $n$, but I'm struggling with the details.

Comment: $(m,n)$ divides $(\left|G\right|,n)$, so necessarily $(m,n)=1$.

Comment: There's many an H throughout that should be a G?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $m$ divides $|G|$, every divisor of $m$ is also a divisor of $|G|$. So whenever $d\ge 1$ divides $m$ and $n$, it must as well be a divisor of $|G|$ and $n$, hence $1$.